# Consuming API with React Native and Axios

Tags: react-native, axios, react-native-flatlist

colleagues. My issue is that when consuming a third party API with React Native and Axios, the data is returned in the console. But they are not rendered in my Flatlist. Please help me! I already tried to create a type but it didn't work.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [matches, setMatches] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() =>{
  axios.get('https://api.football-data.org/v4/competitions/DED/matches?matchday=23',{
    headers: {'X-Auth-Token': '877483580c33490eb7d65f8c0cb96c8d'},
    timeout: 5000
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    setMatches(response.data.results);
  }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
  })
 }, [])
 
return (
    <View>
      <FlatList 
        data={matches}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <View><Text>{item.name}</Text></View>}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Já tentei criar uma type mais nada acontece.

Comment: Hi @HailtonWilsonDosSantos, welcome to SO, Can you please share what are you getting in your `console.log`

Comment: And pls don't share your API key(X-Auth-Token) here... Remove API key ASAP